# How to superscript letters inside an ArrayList when using RecyclerView (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, text-formatting, superscript

I am using Android Studio and I am trying to superscript "st" from 1st inside an ArrayList related to a RecyclerView.  Thank you in advance for your precious help

I tried getString, getText and also through XML but nothing worked. I tried directly in the brackets as well. No result.

Here is the code :

```
List<Model> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
movieList.add(new Model("1st"));
```

I am trying to get 1st ("st" seen as a superscript).

Comment: Want something like this? 1ˢᵗ

Comment: Exactly ^__^ ~ What is the secret ; I am struggling for many days T T

Comment: Dear SnakeException, I just copypasted and now it is working ; thanks a lot. But I was wondering how should I do if I have to bold or use italic. It is not possible to copypaste...

Comment: Simply use fontFamily in xml.